# Lodash - search for item then remove other items that does not match in the object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this multidimensional array and I am doing a search and extracting them.

This is what my object looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Hot Drinks",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Brewed Coffee",
            "price":"90.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Drip Coffee",
            "price":"100.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Cappuccino",
            "price":"100.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Caffe Latte",
            "price":"100.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Caffe Mocha",
            "price":"120.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Cold Drinks",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         {
            "id":6,
            "name":"Iced Coffee",
            "price":"110.00",
            "category_id":2,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":7,
            "name":"Iced Latte",
            "price":"120.00",
            "category_id":2,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":8,
            "name":"Iced Mocha",
            "price":"140.00",
            "category_id":2,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Beverages",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Starters",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         {
            "id":9,
            "name":"Sizzling Sisig",
            "price":"129.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":10,
            "name":"Lumpia Shanghai",
            "price":"149.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":11,
            "name":"Pork & Shrimp Siomai",
            "price":"169.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":12,
            "name":"Spicy Tok Ramen",
            "price":"159.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":14,
            "name":"Humba Rice Meal",
            "price":"110.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":15,
            "name":"Siomai Rice Meal",
            "price":"110.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":16,
            "name":"Sisig Rice Meal",
            "price":"110.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":18,
            "name":"Suman (Pack of 6)",
            "price":"110.00",
            "category_id":4,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "name":"Rice Meals",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         {
            "id":13,
            "name":"Humba Rice Meal",
            "price":"110.00",
            "category_id":5,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":17,
            "name":"Suman & Hot Choco",
            "price":"140.00",
            "category_id":5,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "name":"Desserts",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

This is how i do a search on the menus object.

```
_.filter(this.originalMenus, {menus: [{name: _this.search}] });
```

The problem with this code is that if I searched "Brewed Coffee", it gets the entire `menus` object instead of just the `menus` object with just the "Brewed Coffee" that matches. So the returned result is like this, which is wrong:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Hot Drinks",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Brewed Coffee",
            "price":"90.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Drip Coffee",
            "price":"100.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"Cappuccino",
            "price":"100.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"Caffe Latte",
            "price":"100.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "name":"Caffe Mocha",
            "price":"120.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see it included the other menu items which the Brewed Coffee belongs.

How can I extract it that it looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Hot Drinks",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "menus":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Brewed Coffee",
            "price":"90.00",
            "category_id":1,
            "deleted_at":null,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
      ]
   }
]
```

Apologies if I didn't explain it properly.

Another help if you can include it in your answer is that how can I do a search that partially matches the search, something like `LIKE %search%` in MySQL.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When use like this

```
_.filter(this.originalMenus, {menus: [{name: _this.search}] });
```

It will return all the object inside `this.originalMenus` if `{menus: [{name: _this.search}] }` gets passed.

Basicaly it's filtering `this.originalMenus` when `{menus: [{name: _this.search}] }` gets passed, it's not filtering inner menus, inner menus are used as condition to filter the menu.

so you might need to create a own filtering logic

EX:

```
function filterCofee(search) {
  const filterdMenus = [];

  menus.forEach(menu => {
    // check if there's sub menus that we can filter.
    var filterdMenu = _.filter(menu.menus, { name: search });    

    // if there's matches, then we will add it a array, and return it.
    if (filterdMenu.length > 0) {
      filterdMenus.push({
        ...menu,
        menus: [...filterdMenu]
      });
    }
  });

  return filterdMenus;
}

filterCofee("Brewed Coffee")
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lodash-playground-1234-prhmzl)

---

and if you want to use it like `LIKE %search%`, then replace the above filter with

```
// Here we are checking if the search text included in any of the name at any position.
var filterdMenu = _.filter(menu.menus, (m) => m.name.indexOf(search) >= 0);
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lodash-playground-1234-54rchd)

Comment: Glad it helped!!, if you are using react, then it would be nice if you can wrap the search fn in `useMemo`

Comment: I am actually using VueJS. I added this one in the `@input`. So something like this
`Search Item: <input type="text" placeholder="Search Menu" v-model="search" @input="searchMenu" />`

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider simply using plain vanilla Javascript

```js
const allMenus = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Hot Drinks", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "menus": [{ "id": 1, "name": "Brewed Coffee", "price": "90.00", "category_id": 1, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 2, "name": "Drip Coffee", "price": "100.00", "category_id": 1, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 3, "name": "Cappuccino", "price": "100.00", "category_id": 1, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 4, "name": "Caffe Latte", "price": "100.00", "category_id": 1, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 5, "name": "Caffe Mocha", "price": "120.00", "category_id": 1, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ] }, { "id": 2, "name": "Cold Drinks", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "menus": [{ "id": 6, "name": "Iced Coffee", "price": "110.00", "category_id": 2, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 7, "name": "Iced Latte", "price": "120.00", "category_id": 2, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 8, "name": "Iced Mocha", "price": "140.00", "category_id": 2, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ] }, { "id": 3, "name": "Beverages", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "menus": [ ] }, { "id": 4, "name": "Starters", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "menus": [{ "id": 9, "name": "Sizzling Sisig", "price": "129.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 10, "name": "Lumpia Shanghai", "price": "149.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 11, "name": "Pork & Shrimp Siomai", "price": "169.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 12, "name": "Spicy Tok Ramen", "price": "159.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 14, "name": "Humba Rice Meal", "price": "110.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 15, "name": "Siomai Rice Meal", "price": "110.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 16, "name": "Sisig Rice Meal", "price": "110.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 18, "name": "Suman (Pack of 6)", "price": "110.00", "category_id": 4, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ] }, { "id": 5, "name": "Rice Meals", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "menus": [{ "id": 13, "name": "Humba Rice Meal", "price": "110.00", "category_id": 5, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null }, { "id": 17, "name": "Suman & Hot Choco", "price": "140.00", "category_id": 5, "deleted_at": null, "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ] }, { "id": 6, "name": "Desserts", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "menus": [ ] } ]

const filterBy = (search) => allMenus.map(
  menu => ({
    ...menu,
    menus: menu.menus.filter(({
      name
    }) => name.includes(search))
  })
).filter(({menus}) => menus.length > 0)

console.log(filterBy("Brewed Coffee"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So `_.filter` is going to return true or false for every element in an array and return the array. Because you are filter your top level menus ("Hot Drinks", "Cold Drinks"), the whole thing will be return there if it matches your predicate.

You may be better off using the es6 `.map` function and passing in your own custom function to filter and map the object as you want it to. The `.map` or `.filter` functions are also where you'd be able to do your own logic for partial matches like you were asking.

Otherwise you can do the following to essentially use lodash to do the filter, then use `.map` to remove the extra items from the `menus` array.

```js
var filtered = _.filter(this.originalMenus, {menus: [{name: _this.search}] });
filtered.map(function(m,i){m.menus = _.filter(m.menus,{name: _this.search});
```

but I'd recommend something more along the lines of just using the `.filter` and `.map` functions like this

```js
var filtered = originalMenus.filter((topMenu)=> 
    topMenu.menus.filter((sub)=>
        sub.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())).length > 0)
    .map((m)=>
        {return {...m, ...{menus:m.menus.filter((f)=>f.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))}}}
    )
```